# Telegram login blocked despite correct code - Python Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm working on a Python project that uses Telethon to connect to Telegram. I have the following code for authentication:

```
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash, flood_sleep_threshold=3)
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input(f'Enter the code: {phone} : '))
```

The issue I'm facing is that even when I enter the correct code, Telegram blocks my login attempt with the following message:

```
Telegram blocked an attempt to log in to your account from a new device on 23/10/2023 20:48:02 UTC.

Device: chatbot, 1.31.0, PC 64bit, Android, 4.18.0
Location: Germany (IP = .......)

No one could access your chats because the login was not completed. The code was entered correctly, but login was not allowed because this code was previously shared by your account.
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into why this might be happening? I'm sure the code is correct, but it seems like there's some sort of restriction or block on my account. How can I resolve this and successfully log in using Telethon?

Comment: Do you use 2FA on Telegram?

Comment: No I don't use 2FA password.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the device has remote control enabled like teamviewer. Just close and it will be ok.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).